# PDO: Lookup value and return array of similar values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a Table `'suburb_near'` in my db with columns

```
Area,Council,Suburb,Postcode,State
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,Altona,3018,VIC
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,Altona Meadows,3028,VIC
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,Altona North,3025,VIC
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,Brooklyn (part),3012,VIC
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,Laverton,3028,VIC
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,Newport,3015,VIC
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,Spotswood,3015,VIC
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,Seabrook,3028,VIC
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,Seaholme,3018,VIC
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,South Kingsville,3015,VIC
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,Williamstown,3016,VIC
Western suburbs,City of Hobsons Bay,Williamstown North,3016,VIC
```

I want to input a Suburb and State and then have the Council returned for that Suburb.
I then want to return all other Suburbs which lie in the same Council

```
<?
include("app/config/db.php");
$suburb = "Williamstown";
$state = "VIC";

$st = DBase::singleton()
        ->prepare(
            'select * ' .
            'from `suburb_near` ' .
            'where (`suburb` like :aid AND `state` like :sid)');

$st->bindParam(':aid', $suburb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindParam(':sid', $state, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if ($st->execute())
{
       while ($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {

$council = $row->council;

}
}

echo $council;

?>
```

I can return the Council, but I don't know how to return all the other suburbs.

Comment: Why don't you run another query?

Comment: I would prefer to do it in one, because I don't want the script to become to large and bloated..

Comment: well, your script *already* large and bloated, being four times bigger than needed. Anyway, if you need particular SQL, then you have to ask a question on that particular sql, without any PHP code. Consider using join.

Comment: can you suggest a way to cut down my existing script?  this is what I found to work with PDO prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming Suburb+State combination unique,

```
<?
include("app/config/db.php");
$suburb = "Williamstown";
$state = "VIC";

$sql = 'select t2.* from suburb_near t1 
        JOIN suburb_near t2 ON t1.council = t2.council
        where t1.suburb = ? AND t1.state = ?';
$st  = DBase::singleton()->prepare($sql);
$st->execute(array($suburb,$state));
$data = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach($data as $row)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

but you really need to normalize your table structure, having distinct tables for all the entities involved.

Comment: thanks I'm using php5.3 so I'm getting an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' I'm upgrading to php5.5 to see if the solution works

Comment: just change [] to outdated array() syntax. no big deal. that's not the point of the code

Comment: the $data is only echoing "Array"

Comment: 'select * ' .
   'from `suburb_near` ' .
   'where `council` like (select `council` from `suburb_near` where (`suburb` like :aid AND `state` like :sid)');  this doesn't work also

Comment: i need it to return all the other suburbs which reside in the same council